# Mailgun - Corrupted pdf attachment

Tags: node.js, pdf, mailgun

I am sending a file using the mailgun-js module in NodeJS. The original file is fine, but the one I receive is corrupted.

I am using the code below to send my file. The array `infos.attachements` contains the path and name of the files I want to send.

```
 var file = fs.readFileSync(infos.attachments[0].path),
 attch = new mailgun.Attachment({data: file, filename:infos.attachments[0].name , contentType: 'application/pdf'}),
 mailOptions = {
   from: 'sender address'
   to: 'receiver address',
   attachment:[attch],
   subject: 'some subject', // Subject line
   text: 'text content'
 };

 mailgun.messages().send(mailOptions, function(error, body){...
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `attch` enclosed within square brackets? In the code reference for the [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js#attachments) module, it seems that variable is not enclosed within it.

Comment: Ultimately I'll have several attachments, so I was preparing the field for it. The documentation you are mentioning states that "Multiple attachments can be sent by passing an array in the attachment parameter.", so I guess it should be fine...
Also, I just tested without the brackets with the same result.